# asp.net Button Onclick event did't fire its code behind function

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Using asp button in asp.net page. Rendering this button in code behind as html string and assigned to div.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ProImg" runat="server" CssClass="Photo" ImageUrl="~/images/ProfilePage/pic.jpg"
                    ImageAlign="Middle" OnClick="ProImg_Click" />
```

the render scenario is

```
Control MyApps = tabsUL.FindControl("MyApp");
string MyAppshtml = RenderControl(MyApps);
outerTabInfo.InnerHtml =  MyAppTxt;
```

And the rendercontrol function is

```
private string RenderControl(Control control)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    control.RenderControl(writer);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But it actually didn't fire **ProgImg_Click** function.The Function is

```
protected void ProImg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code process
}
```

Thn How can i make it....Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you defined this method, `ProImg_Click` ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us how your ProImg_Click function and tell us how do you know it is not executed?

Comment: i set break point on that function and it did't reach the block...

Comment: sry where is the answer @Lajos...

Comment: @jai I don't see how in your RenderControl method you attach the OnClick event to the ProImg_Click event handler

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event programaticaly

```
private string RenderControl(Control control)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    if(control.Id=="ProImg"){
      control.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ProImg_Click);

     }
    control.RenderControl(writer);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```